# how to write the code for download button in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my DB I have saved the address of a pdf file as string type, now how can I download it by clicking download button??? I need the help to write the code for my download button...

```
    <td bgcolor="#CCE6FF" class="style7"> Chapter 1 <br /> 
                <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" onclick="Button6_Click" Text="pdf"  />
              </td>
```

In my DB there are 4 columns ChapterID(pk),Name,Document and SubjectId(fk). In document column I have saved the pdf file address as string. Now I want, when I click the download button it should be able to download the file... How can I do that?????

Answer (score 0):

try th above

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(WDriveFilePath)

FileStream file = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(MyLocalFile)); 

file.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFilePath");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        //// Create a form to contain the grid
        var frm = new HtmlForm();
        frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        frm.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Hope this helps..:)